# Where's the management interface for IISExpress?

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-express

Is there an interface separate from the regular IIS manager?

When I search on IISExpress I find only a link to a folder full of logs related to IISExpress sites that had been spawned by Visual Studio.

Comment: Related to this, the config files are located in `%userprofile%\documents\IISExpress`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314928/where-is-the-iis-express-install-directory

Comment: For those of you having the same problem in Windows 10. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901434/iis-manager-in-windows-10

Comment: For the same problem in Windows 10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901434/iis-manager-in-windows-10

Comment: Download the "IIS: Management Console" from the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

Comment: You can only resort to open source projects. One of them is created by me, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [WebMatrix, or Visual Studios](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) to manage web sites in IIS Express.

Or, if you like the [command line](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/) you can use the files located in `c:\Program Files\IIS Express` or `c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express`

Comment: No dude.  There's a GUI app to manage it; you can download it from the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, what is this GUI app called in Web PI? Alternately, what are the steps to find it?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, dude, there's a billion things in the WPI. Which one is it?

Comment: It's called Web Matrix

Comment: WebMatrix is now dead, https://forums.iis.net/t/1233133.aspx?VS+Code+and+WebMatrix+no+longer+in+development+ . Also starting from 2014, I started an open source project Jexus Manager to fill the gaps Microsoft left, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/

Answer (score 9):

There isn't an equivalent to the normal IIS7 control panel that I'm aware of, but when IIS Express is running there is usually a management tool that appears in the system tray that will let you do things like shut down or remove sites or recycle processes.

Comment: There is a GUI management tool, you just have to install it separately from the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: where? how is it called? :)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Even in 2017 you wouldn't get anything from Web Platform Installer to manage IIS Express in IIS Manager manner.

Comment: @Lex Li, Awesome tool! You managed to do what a company valued at nearly $1T couldn't do. Microsoft could've added IIS Express support in IIS Manager with a laughably trivial amount of effort. You did it without an existing code base. I would bill Microsoft for the hours you spent on it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, my friend. But my own answer here was kindly deleted by @MichaelHampton.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source tool:

https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager

https://www.jexusmanager.com/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can download the management control panel from [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

Comment: That does not work for IIS Express.